# Query distinct property and return complete nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I got a lot of nodes, some with similar values in field `X`, I want to select by distinct `X` values and take **all the popular nodes (order by some other field `Y`) with all their properties**.

**Example:**

> ID | X | Y | Name
>
> 1  | A | 100 | David
>
> 2  | A | 10  | Chris
>
> 3  | B | 5   | Brad
>
> 4  | B | 25  | Amber

**Should return:**

> 1 | A | 100 | David
>
> 4 | B | 25  | Amber

I managed to get the list by distinct `X`:

```
MATCH (u:NodeType)
RETURN DISTINCT u.X
```

I need to find the most popular (highest value of `Y`) nodes to join with my distinct nodes (which are now only a single property) and return whole nodes (with all the properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an [arg max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max)-style query. I recently [answered a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595890/getting-the-max-record-with-different-values-using-cypher/47596303#47596303) using [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect):

```
MATCH (u:NodeType)
WITH u
ORDER BY u.Y DESC
WITH u.X AS X, collect(u)[0] AS u
RETURN u
```

The idea is the following:

1. Order by the value of `Y` (descending).
2. Implicitly group by the values of `X` and for the aggregating function, use `collect` to gather other values to a list. The elements of the list are the nodes (which are still stored according to a descending order of `Y`).
3. For each collected list, select the first element with `[0]`.

Maybe the query is a bit easier to read if you perform the last step in a separate clause (and not in the `WITH` clause that performs the `collect`):

```
MATCH (u:NodeType)
WITH u
ORDER BY u.Y DESC
WITH u.X AS X, collect(u) AS us
RETURN us[0] AS u
```

Comment: Good answer, but the Cypher syntax is not quite correct. For instance, the first query should be something like this: `MATCH (u:NodeType) WITH u ORDER BY u.Y DESC WITH u.X AS x, COLLECT(u)[0] AS u RETURN u;`

Comment: Good point, thanks! I edited the post quite extensively and this slipped through.